# Intersection of Infinite Regular Language with CFL

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, context-free

Intersection of any finite regular language with anything( CFL or not CFL) will be finite but what about intersection of infinite regular language with CFL or not CFL. Does the resultant will be finite or not ?

Answer (score 0):

It can be both. Infinite regular language intersection with $Σ^*$ will be infinite and intersection with $Φ$ will be a finite set. Both $Σ^*$ & $Φ$  are regular languages, and therefore are context free as well.